# What are Unity Cloth vertices offset from?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use the position of a cloth vertex to attach an object to it (a rope to the corner of a sail), but I'm having a hard time figuring out what exactly the `cloth.vertices` vectors mean. They're clearly an offset from something, but from what? I'm drawing a sphere at `cloth.transform.TransformPoint(vertex);` and it's *close* to the actual drawn vertex of the cloth, but it's not quite right. It's not like I just have the wrong vertex, because the drawn sphere is totally outside of the cloth.

I've tried other things like transforming from the mesh's transform, from the parent object's transform, etc. but I can't figure out what the cloth vertices actually mean, so I was hoping someone out there knows more about it.